# How to have Movie clip rotate at certain point of another Movie clip?

Tags: actionscript-3, rotation, point, flash-cs6, flashdevelop

Hey everyone so still going at this for a couple days now. Still can't figure out how to accomplish this...

So I have a movie clip called `cannon` inside this movie clip I have an empty movie clip called `firePoint` now what I am trying to do is have a movie clip called `ball` shoot out of the empty movie clip point `firePoint`. The `cannon`is rotating and the cannons registration point is middle. I want the `ball` to rotate with the `cannon` at the cannons firePoint.

Whenever I try to do this or even if I add the ball to the cannons firePoint the ball doesnt position near the cannon at all but rather on the top left hand screen. Also the ball doesnt rotate at the end of the cannon which is the firePoint.

Here is what I have so far inside my constructor:

```
        cannon = new mcCannon();
        cannon.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2);
        cannon.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2);
        stage.addChild(cannon);

        globalFirePoint = localToGlobal(new Point(cannon.firePoint.x, cannon.firePoint.y));

        ball = new mcBall();
        stage.addChild(ball);

        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, logicHandler);
```

inside the ENTER_FRAME event is where I have the cannon rotating and I know in order to have my ball rotate with the cannon I need it to be in the ENTER_FRAME as well like so:

```
private function logicHandler(e:Event):void 
    {
        cannon.rotation ++;

        ball.x = globalFirePoint.x;
        ball.y = globalFirePoint.y;
    }
```

the above code doesn't do anything but spawn the ball at the wrong position and only rotate the cannon. I have tried so much and still fail. All I want is for the ball to position correctly and rotate with the cannon at the cannons `firePoint` so I can later have the ball shoot at different angles.

Please any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: First of all your globalfirepoint is not updating and its initialized only once. Secondly, why don't you add the ball to the fire point movie clip itself? This way you won't have to worry about rotation as it would rotate with its parent?

Comment: Oh okay that makes sense. But with the Adding the ball movie clip to the firePoint causes a issue with the ball firing from that point. When I setup the mouse event to fire the ball out of the rotating cannon the ball will rotate as well and not go in a straight line on the angle in which it was shot from so doing this cannon.firePoint.addchild(ball); wont work correctly :/

Comment: the ball will curve whenever it is shot.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Maybe do it this way: add the ball to the firepoint, let it rotate along unless the fire event happens. Then remove that ball from the firepoint mc, calculate global position once and then add a new ball on the stage and animate its trajectory. This way you won't have to recalculate positions in every frame?

Comment: Interesting. That sounds like it might work out. But when you say animate you mean create a new movie clip object ball and have it tween in a straight line?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant to say :) hope it works out. Cheers

Comment: Alright I will give it a shot thanks for the help!